# Does VS 2015 use Kestrel?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr, kestrel-http-server

I am using VS 2015 Update3.
I have ASP.NET core web api with the following Program.cs code

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()       
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000")         
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Then in VS I have configured IIS Express to run on port `40000`

This is how launchSettings.json looks like

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40000/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/workunit",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000/api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I press F5 to run app using Visual Studio. When i make a request to API i get the result back so everything works fine.
In Program.cs I have `.UseIISIntegration()`. So I was under impression when request comes to IIS express, it just forwards that request to Kestrel. 
So I thought both IIS Express and Kestrel has to run at the same time on 2 different ports.

However when I ran `netstat -ab` command I noticed IIS express is running on port 40000 as expected but nothing is running on port `5000`.  In-fact just to test I changed IIS Express port also to `5000` and it worked fine. I was expecting conflict between IIS Express and Kestrel, but that didn't happen.

So question is does VS 2015 uses Kestrel at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VisualStudio does use Kestrel. The trick is that when Kestrel is used behind IIS/IISExpress it is not using the port you specified. Rather, IIS chooses a random port which it will use for communication and this is the port Kestrel has to be using (the port is overriden in the `UseIISIntegration`). If you are running Kestrel directly `.UseIISIntegration` is just a no-op and therefore Kestrel will listen on the port you specified in `UseUrls`. One of consequences of this is that the order of `.UseUrls` and `.UseIISIntegration` is important - if you put `.UseUrls` after `.UseIISIntegration` you would always override the port and as a result you would not be able to start your application with IIS. 
If you want to exactly what is happening take a look at a [blog post](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/) I wrote on this very subject.